# In Firestore security rules, does doing request.resource.data() account for first time writes?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, rules

```
match /databases/{database}/documents 
  {
    match /users/{theuser=**}
    {
     match /prescriptions/{prescriptions}
      {
      allow read, write: if
     (request.resource.data.TheClinicianEmail == request.auth.token.email);
      }
}
}
```

In this example, I am checking the field of "TheClinicianEmail" for the document 'prescription'. When creating this document for the first time, will request.resource.data just be the data that I pass in, since no document exists yet?

```
await db.collection('users').doc(Theemail).collection('Prescription').add({
           
            TheClinicianEmail: Theemail,
        })
```

Here I add the field -> TheClinicianEmail, when the document gets created for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.resource.data` is *always* the data being passed up by the client (the request).

`resource.data` is the data that is already in Firestore, if any.